# Display next element which is not a sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code. I want the class 'moreDetails' to be shown only when the user clicks the 'View More' button

```
    <tr class="currentRow">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>johndoe@example.com</td>

    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moreDetails(this)">View More</button></td></tr>
    <tr class = moreDetails>
    <td>
             Additional details
    </td>
    </tr>         
    <tr>
```

Here is my java script. I have tried all versions of next(), .parent(), prev() etc. I couldnt get it working. Can you please help?

```
function moreDetails(obj){

          $(obj).closest('.currentRow').find('moreDetails').show();

}
```

Comment: add a period to your class selector, `$(obj).closest('.currentRow').find('.moreDetails').show();`

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I did have the period originally. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `find('moreDetails')` to `find('.moreDetails')` .

```
$(obj).closest('.currentRow').find('.moreDetails').show();
```

OR

```
$(obj).parent().next().show();
```

OR

```
$(obj).parent().next('.moreDetails').show();
```

EDIT :

If the `html` is this

```
<tr class="currentRow">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moreDetails(this)">View More</button></td>
</tr>
<tr class = moreDetails>
    <td> Additional details</td>
</tr>
```

Then use

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().show();
```

Comment: `$(obj).closest('.currentRow').find('.moreDetails').show();` cant use this because `moreDetails` isnt a child of `currentRow` but a sibling

Answer (score 0):

1. `<tr class = moreDetails>` is missing the quotes around the class name. It should be `<tr class="moreDetails">`
2. When the page loads, as per your requirement, you need to hide the `<tr class="moreDetails"` element. So, use `style="display:none"` to hide the div in initial state.

One of the solutions using Javascript only

```js
function moreDetails(){
  var moreDetailElement = document.querySelector(".moreDetails");
  moreDetailElement.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="currentRow">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>johndoe@example.com</td>

    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moreDetails()">View More</button></td></tr>
    <tr class="moreDetails" style="display:none">
    <td>
             Additional details
    </td>
    </tr>         
    </table>
```

Comment: Code is not instance specific. Add another row and it breaks

Comment: And also I wanted the same thing to happen for other rows too down the line. So I cannot select that class directly and show it. But anyways thanks for responding and trying to help me out. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').closest('.currentRow').next('.moreDetails').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="currentRow">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>johndoe@example.com</td>

    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="moreDetails(this)">View More</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='moreDetails'>
    <td>
      Additional details
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Use `.closest()` with `.next()`.

1. Use `.closest('.currentRow')` or `.closest('tr')` to get the parent tr.
2. Use `.next('.moreDetails')` to get the tr you want to show